# Apply for Blue card from Home country & the documents required for it

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, blue-card

I'm currently applying for a job in Germany. A company asked me to apply for Blue Card so that I'm eligible to work in Germany. Since I'm residing in Pakistan, I'm not sure how to proceed with this applying of Blue Card.

My profession is unregulated in Germany.

**The documents that I have readied for this purpose:**

1. University Diploma (original) already attested from Higher Education Commission in Pakistan. - This document is in English
2. University Transcript (original) that contains courses and scores already attested from Higher Education Commission. - This document is in English
3. All the documents from my College and High School
4. Passport
5. Job Contract letter
6. 2 Passport size photographs
7. Certificate from law offices in Pakistan that I'm not a public, health or security threat and I haven't been arrested in my life.

**My Questions are:**

1. `Can I apply for Blue Card while residing in Pakistan` because *I have received the job contract* or does the embassy offers some temporary visa so that I can go to Germany and upon arrival, I have to get Blue Card from Embassy in Germany?
2. Do I need to get the `photocopies` of my University Diploma and Transcript *attested from Higher Education Commission*? The **original** Diploma and Transcript are **already** attested and the attestation stamp is visible in the photocopies.
3. Do I need to get the `photocopies` of my College and High School documents attested from Higher Education Commission?
4. Do I need health insurance certificate, if yes, how much should be the `value` of the health insurance for traveling to Germany?
5. `Antrag auf Erteilung eines Aufenthaltstitels` where can I get this? Does my employer has to provide this document because currently I'm residing in Pakistan.
6. What's the *statement of Comparability*? Is it **ZAB**?
7. *What other documents and stuff should I get ready before I applying for EU blue card in Pakistan?*

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

you *must* apply for your bluecard from your current location.

you need to do this through the local German Mission: http://www.pakistan.diplo.de

this page specifically should give you an overview of the visa process with them:  http://www.pakistan.diplo.de/Vertretung/pakistan/en/06Legal/2__visa__longterm/__Visa__longterm.html

you should contact the mission with your questions because *they* will be handling your application, hence you need to meet their requirements.  Best way to do this is to get the information directly from them.

the faq for bluecard questions on the BAMF website gives a lot of information, too: sadly I can't post more than two links but I'm sure you can find it if you search for BAMF bluecard faq ;)

Comment: http://www.pakistan.diplo.de/Vertretung/pakistan/en/06Legal/2__visa__longterm/__Visa__longterm.html

provides information for someone who is looking for a job and it also requires that person to present German/English Certifiication and financial statement. Since I have already gotten the job, I don't think I need to provide language certificatoin or financial statement. Please correct me if I am wrong